# d3 js transition not working

Tags: ajax, d3.js

i'm trying to create a graph in d3.js after taking data from views.py in Django:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
              <div class="x_panel tile fixed_height_320 overflow_hidden">
                <div class="x_title">
                  <h2>Power</h2>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                    <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Settings 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Settings 2</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="x_content">
                  <table class="" style="width:100%">

                    <tr>

                      <td id="area1" role="button">
                        <script>
                            $('#area1').ready(function(){

                               $.ajax({
                                   type:'GET',
                                   url:'/',
                                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                   dataType: 'json',
                                   success : function(data)
                                   {

                                    var width = 250,
                                    height = 250,
                                    twoPi = 2 * Math.PI;

                                    var arc1 = d3.svg.arc()
                                    .innerRadius(100)
                                    .outerRadius(120)
                                    .startAngle(0);

                                    var svg1 = d3.select("#area1").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", width)
                                    .attr("height", height)
                                    .append("g")
                                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

                                    var meter1 = svg1.append("g")
                                    .attr("class", "season-progress");

                                    var background = meter1.append("path")
                                    .datum({endAngle: twoPi})
                                    .style("fill", "#ffb74d")
                                    .attr("d", arc1);

                                    var foreground = meter1.append("path")
                                    .datum({endAngle:0})
                                    .style("fill", "#e65100")
                                    .attr("class", "foreground")
                                    .attr("d", arc1);

                                    foreground.transition()
                                    .duration(1000)
                                    .ease("linear")
                                    .attrTween("d", function(d) {
                                               var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, twoPi * data['ITPOWER'] / data['AVAILABLEPOWER']);
                                               return function(t) {
                                                  d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
                                                  return arc1(d);
                                               }
                                            });

                                    var text =  meter1.append("text")
                                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                                    .attr("dy", "1.5em")
                                    .attr("font-size", "18")
                                        .style('fill','#4B515D')
                                    .text('PuE');

                                    var line2 = meter1.append("text")
                                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                                    .attr("dy", ".10em")
                                    .attr("font-size", "30")
                                        .style('fill','#4B515D')
                                    .text(Math.round(data["PuE"]*100)/100);
                                   }
                               });
                            });
                        </script>

                            </td>
                      <td>
                        <table class="tile_info">
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <p> </p>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <p style="color:#e65100;">Used </p>
                            </td>

                            <td >{{ power.ITPOWER }}kWh</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <p style="color:#ffb74d;">Available </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ power.AVAILABLEPOWER }}kWh</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <p style="color:#4B515D;">Usage </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>15%</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <p> </p>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

I'm getting this :

[my complete web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsk6C.png)

but when I try the same thing with just the graph on the html page, I get what I wanted:

[the transition is getting executed here,but not in the first case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFTdY.png)

Please explain why I'm able to see the transition when the graph is the only element on the html page and not otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a bootstrap template available online.This template was using Jquery for other elements on the web page.These were messing my d3.js graph. I deleted those elements as I did not need them.